# Issue related to Searching Data in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have SQL datatable StudetnMaster having `FirstName nvarchar(100)` and contains Data Entry Gujarati Language (Unicode Chracters)

**Sample:**

```
   StudentId   FirstName
     1           ઘનશ્યામ
     2           જીગર
```

Now I have following query for searching:

```
Select * 
from StudetnMaster 
where FirstName like N'" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%'
```

It's working fine but in stored procedure I have to pass parameter for `FirstName` as Follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1
        @FirstName nvarchar(100)
AS
    select * 
    from StudentNew 
    where FirstName like N@FirstName+'%'
```

But it throws an Error saying :

> Invalid Column Name N@FirstName

How can I use `'N'`  in SP for parameter because without using `N'` Unicode Text is not searchable?

For inline query as mentioned above i got result, but for stored procedure I got error, so how can we use `'N'` in SP?

Is there any other solution for searching unicode characters in SP?

Thanks

Comment: No need to add `N`. Just try `select * from StudentNew where FirstName like @FirstName+'%'`

Answer (score 1):

Just like in comment was written- you dont have to add N to parameter.

As you define parameter as nvarchar, it means- 2 bytes per symbol (that what N stands for, when you write N'string').

If that necessary, you can add collation there:

```
select * from StudentNew
where FirstName like @FirstName+'%' Collate YourCollationName
```